# Win32_Services. Service retrieval through python from a remote machine

Tags: python, wmi, win32com, wmi-query

I am making a web application to monitor certain servers and part of that is monitoring specific services that should be running in those servers. I made a simple python script that tests the Win32_service function that should retrieve all running services. Here is the code:

```
import wmi

def get_running_services(computer, user, password):
    try:
        # Connect to the remote WMI service
        connection = wmi.WMI(computer=computer, user=user, password=password)
        print(f"Successfully connected to {computer}")

        # Get details about running services
        running_services = []
        for service in connection.Win32_Service(State="Running"):
            running_services.append({
                "name": service.Name,
                "display_name": service.DisplayName,
                "status": service.Status,
            })

        # Print details about each running service
        for service in running_services:
            print(f"Service Name: {service['name']}")
            print(f"Display Name: {service['display_name']}")
            print(f"State: {service['state']}")
            print(f"Status: {service['status']}")
            print("-" * 50)

        return running_services
    except wmi.x_wmi as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to {computer}: {str(e)}")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return None

get_running_services(IP, User, Password)
```

And this is my output:
Successfully connected to 192.168.xxx.xxx
Failed to connect to 192.168.xxx.xxx: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217405, 'OLE error 0x80041003', None, None)>

Credentials are changed on purpose for security purposes but they are correct.

As you can see, the first connection is succesfull and this is because I have made every change necessary to grant permission for my computer to connect to the remote server. I have been searching for hours for a solution but I can't seem to find one. Does anyone know what permission I need to set up in order to be able to retrieve the services?

I tried giving permision to my local user from the remote service using dcomcnfg and wmimgmt.msc and allowing inbound rules in the firewall advance setiings as well as creating a new traffic WMI rule that should allow connections from unspecified hosts. (I know this is not secure I am testing the program first on a dummy server)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by running sc sdset SCMANAGER D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)
in the remote console

Comment: I fixed the permissions problem and I am able to access the remote computer services but it still won't return most services. Why dows it only return some of them? Also, I ran this script in two different remote hosts that have many services running in common and one of them gives me some services that the other won't give me. What do I do?